# Finding gaps between intervals using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following problem: given a set of **non-overlapping** intervals in a data.table, report the gaps between the intervals.

I have implemented this once in SQL, however I am struggling with data.table due to the lack of a lead function or lag function. For completeness, I have [here](http://pastebin.com/X8VpkKJH) the SQL code. I know the functionality has been implemented in data.table version 1.9.5. as by the [changelog](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table). So is this possible with data.table without doing a lot of merges and without a lag or lead function?

In principle, I am not fully against using merges (aka joins) as long as performance does not suffer. I think this has an easy implementation, but I can't figure out how to "get" the previous end time to be the starting time of my gap table.

For example:

```
# The numbers represent seconds from 1970-01-01 01:00:01
dat <- structure(
  list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
       stime = structure(c(as.POSIXct("2014-01-15 08:00:00"),
                           as.POSIXct("2014-01-15 11:00:00"),
                           as.POSIXct("2014-01-16 11:30:00"),
                           as.POSIXct("2014-01-15 09:30:00"),
                           as.POSIXct("2014-01-15 12:30:00"),
                           as.POSIXct("2014-01-15 13:30:00")
                           ),
                         class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
       etime = structure(c(as.POSIXct("2014-01-15 10:30:00"),
                           as.POSIXct("2014-01-15 12:00:00"),
                           as.POSIXct("2014-01-16 13:00:00"),
                           as.POSIXct("2014-01-15 11:00:00"),
                           as.POSIXct("2014-01-15 12:45:00"),
                           as.POSIXct("2014-01-15 14:30:00")
                           ), 
                         class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
  ),
  .Names = c("ID", "stime", "etime"),
  sorted = c("ID", "stime", "etime"),
  class = c("data.table", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA,-6L)
)

dat <- data.table(dat)
```

This results in:

```
ID               stime               etime
1  2014-01-15 10:30:00 2014-01-15 11:00:00
1  2014-01-15 12:00:00 2014-01-16 11:30:00
2  2014-01-15 11:00:00 2014-01-15 12:30:00
2  2014-01-15 12:45:00 2014-01-15 13:30:00
```

Notice: the gaps are reported evenly across days.

Comment: Aren't you missing a row here or I'm missing something?

Comment: side note: `dat <- data.table(dat)` is a waste of memory.. use `setDT(dat)` instead.

Comment: I think this can be done with minor changes to @eddi's answer in your previous Q.

Comment: Dear David, yes I was missing one row. Thank you for noticing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variation on David's answer, likely a little less efficient, but simpler to type out:

```
setkey(dat, stime)[, .(stime=etime[-.N], etime=stime[-1]), by=ID]
```

Produces:

```
   ID               stime               etime
1:  1 2014-01-15 10:30:00 2014-01-15 11:00:00
2:  1 2014-01-15 12:00:00 2014-01-16 11:30:00
3:  2 2014-01-15 11:00:00 2014-01-15 12:30:00
4:  2 2014-01-15 12:45:00 2014-01-15 13:30:00
```

setkey is just to make sure table is sorted by time.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm not missing something, you are missing a row in your desired output, so here's my attempt using `shift` from the devel version as you mentioned.

```
library(data.table) ## v >= 1.9.5
indx <- dat[, .I[-.N], by = ID]$V1
dat[, .(ID, stimes = etime, etime = shift(stime, type = "lead"))][indx]
res
#    ID               stime               etime
# 1:  1 2014-01-15 10:30:00 2014-01-15 11:00:00
# 2:  1 2014-01-15 12:00:00 2014-01-16 11:30:00
# 3:  2 2014-01-15 11:00:00 2014-01-15 12:30:00
# 4:  2 2014-01-15 12:45:00 2014-01-15 13:30:00
```